# Will an Apple Airport router work better with my Macs?

Tags: macbook-pro, airport

I recently upgraded from Windows to a Mac, and now I have two Macbooks. Would they work better with my wireless if I got an Apple Airport a/b/n router? (I couldn't find anything about this on Google or anywhere else.)

Comment: What doesn't work well enough with your current router that you are hoping to improve on? Are you having specific problems? The Airport routers work very well - I have an Extreme and several Express models, but don't just buy one because it's from Apple.

Comment: the one i have is fine, but i was curious if there are any advantages of getting an apple router to match the computers. Similar to if you have a netgear router have better connectivity with netgear wireless cards

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much that AirPort routers will work "better", but I can guarantee that setup of AirPort routers when using Mac computers is *much* easier than other routers.  The AirPort Utility really makes setup a breeze!

This comes from years of experience as a network admin and having personally owned/used at least one of just about every major brand of home router.  If you can afford an AirPort router, you won't regret the purchase.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i am not a network admin but i do consider myself network savvy. I have a netgear wndr3700 right now but i dont own any windows machines anymore. I figured that maybe an apple airport router might work better or be more compatible as both are made by the same vendor. I have to do some more research, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The Apple Airport router will work better in the sense that it allows you to use some additional features, including "[Wake on Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774)" (included with Snow Leopard):

> The Wake on Demand feature of Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard lets your Mac continue to share items (such as music, printers, files, or your screen) when it is asleep.

Comment: thanks, are there any other goodies i should know about?

Comment: You can [stream music](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/features/airplay.html) to speakers connected to an Airport Express.